# How to get table's first column td value in angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

Tried to get table's first column td value after selected dropdown change values but not working.
I want to get first column td value after selected dropdown in angular 6.
I have given my code below. Anyone can have idea?please help to find the solution.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="wrapperTbl">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>YearJoined</th>
        <th>Missions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let astronaut of astronautsToBeSelected" class="clickable">
        <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.id}}</td>
        <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.name}}</td>
        <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.job}}</td>
        <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.year_joined}}</td>
        <select (change)="selected()">
        <option *ngFor="let mission of astronaut.missions" [selected]="mission.name == 'back'">{{mission}} </option>
        </select>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-show-the-dynamic-table-with-dropdown-in-angular-todepv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following -

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let astronaut of astronautsToBeSelected" class="clickable">
            <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.id}}</td>
            <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.name}}</td>
            <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.job}}</td>
            <td (click)="selectAstronaut(astronaut)">{{astronaut.year_joined}}</td>
            <td><select (change)="selected($event, astronaut.id)">
            <option *ngFor="let mission of astronaut.missions" [selected]="mission.name == 'back'">{{mission}} </option>
            </select>
      </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

When you want to access any event, you will need the $event in the html. You can also pass additional parameters you want.

```
selected(event, id){

   //tbal id is wrapperTbl

alert(event.target.value + '|' + id )


}
```

Hope this helps.